# Determine when all init functions have completed?

Tags: jquery

We have a JavaScript/JQuery page with a number of "initialization functions" a la:

```
$(function(){
  //Do stuff
}
```

Is there a programmatic way you can determine when all these methods have completed running?

We could set a boolean variable to true in the last function()...  was wondering if there was a more elegant way.

??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to determine if they have run, use `$.isReady`, it'll be true when the DOM's ready to go, it's not set until just before executing all the handlers...so the pretty-much-being-single-threaded-ness would work you you there.

If you want to queue something to execute (it must be queued *before* `document.ready` fires), bind it to `"ready"`, like this:

```
$(document).bind("ready", function() { alert("All ready functions ran"); });
```

[You can see how it's fired here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/core.js#L433), note that this is *not* the same as `$(document).ready()`, [which is another function](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/core.js#L256).

Comment: $.isReady doesn't seem to work for me.  Setting a boolean variable to true in the last function() does work..   Note that I am referring to this ready indicator in jqGrid loadComplete callback methods to see if the callback is getting called for the initial load or subsequent loads.

Comment: @Marcus - which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @Marcus - You're not seeing it as `true` after all `ready` once the document is?  (Try it on the console in this page to see it working)

Comment: I appear to be seeing it as true before ALL function(){} methods are finished executing..  I "want it" to be true only AFTER the methods have executed..

Comment: @Marcus - jqGrid `loadComplete` is the result of an asynchronous function, is it not? If so nothing's waiting on it...your jQuery ready handlers did complete, they wouldn't wait on any asynchronous activity before moving on.

Comment: Right it is async..  though the "mechanism" of setting a boolean variable in the last function() works fine in the async methods..  why would this work but not isReady?

Comment: @Marcus - because the `ready` methods *have* completed, it's the callback that could return *anytime* later that haven't completed...if you need to wait on those, you need to set your own boolean.

Comment: @Nick Craver, I confused the behavior of this script running the event ready to documents in this way: http://jsfiddle.net/KFbwp/ , my result is in Chrome "0 2 1a 1a"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all your initialisation "stuff" is synchronous, you can call a function at the end of the last one on your page, in which you can execute code in the knowledge that everything has been initialised.

```
$(function(){
  //Do stuff

  run();
}

function run() {
  // we are initialised now...
}
```

While this isn't exactly what you asked for, it removes the need for checking that the initialisation functions have completed running... as soon as they have the `run` function will be called.

Answer (score 1):

try [this (example)](http://jsfiddle.net/pyAgJ/):

HTML:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

JS:

```
(function ($) {

    var 
        owReady = $.ready,
        readyEndList = [];

    $.ready = function () {

        var 
            toEnd = owReady(),
            fn, i = 0;

        if (toEnd)
            return toEnd;

        if (!$.isReady)
            return toEnd; 

        while ( (fn = readyEndList[ i++ ]) ) {
            fn.call( document, jQuery );
        }

        readyEndList = null;

        return toEnd;

    };

    $.addToEndReady = function(fn) {

        if ($.isFunction(fn))
            readyEndList.push(fn);
    };

    $(function (ev) {

        $('#test').append('<span>0</span><br />');

        $.addToEndReady(function(){

            $('#test').append('<span>end</span><br />');

        });

    });

    // inicio del modulo
    $(function (ev) {

        $('#test').append('<span>1</span><br />');

    });

    $(function (ev) {

        $('#test').append('<span>2</span><br />');

    });

} (jQuery));
```